# Emacs 23.2 with ECB 2.40 | File error: Cannot open load file, semantic-ctxt

Tags: emacs, elisp

How I can use the Emacs Code Browser v2.40 with my fresh installed Emacs 23.2 (Debian distro)

In my init.el I have:

```
(semantic-mode)
(add-to-list 'load-path
  "~/.emacs.d/plugins/ecb-2.40")
(require 'ecb)
```

When I run Emacs, I get an Error message on statrup:

> File error: Cannot open load file, semantic-ctxt

I have read CEDET suite is build in from Emacs 23, so I don't have installed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This did the trick for me with 2.40:

```
(require 'semantic/analyze)
(provide 'semantic-analyze)
(provide 'semantic-ctxt)
(provide 'semanticdb)
(provide 'semanticdb-find)
(provide 'semanticdb-mode)
(provide 'semantic-load)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/ecb-2.40")
(require 'ecb)
```

I haven't been using it for long, but the obvious features seem to work.

UPDATE: or you can just use the [latest CVS snapshot](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/cvs_snapshots/ecb.tar.gz), it's updated for integrated CEDET.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have complained about problems with the CEDET shipped with Emacs 23.2, so I recommend you to try using the standalone CEDET distribution and see if you have the problem with it as well.

Comment: I have tried both, the 1.0pre6 and the 1.0pre7 packages, build through my emacs, but still the same problem. Anyway I have found a much nicer approch: http://code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/ awesome

Comment: Emacs-nav seems very nice indeed - it seems that a Google engineer developed it...